# How to insert a letter on bottom of symbol \leq?

Tags: symbols

[image: equation]

How to make like this on latex? Please help me, thanks for advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$(A\cup B,\underset{A,B}{\le'})=(B\cup A,\underset{A,B}{\le'})$
\end{document}
```

[image]